# Javascript isn't storing my variable

Tags: javascript, function, scope

For some reason my variable isn't being stored when leaving the scope in the if statement. Code is below. I am pretty new to javascript, so I am a little unsure if it's a small fix?

```
            var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
            var lng = '';
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                lng = ''+results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                alert(lng); // prints out the lng()
              }
            })

            alert(lng); // prints out blank
```

Comment: define your variable `lng` outside the function body

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher That is already the case.

Comment: var lng; outside of function

Comment: Sorry @HyyanAboFakher, that was a typo :(

Comment: To anyone suggesting defining the variable somewhere else: it's not the problem, and it won't help. Read the duplicate.

Comment: It is because you are using an asynchronous function

Comment: The duplicate is really helpful, still trying to read the whole answer and trying to understand it though loll

Comment: The variable assignment happens after the alert is executed